# Giving another developer access to docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm using docker-compose to deploy services to a remote docker-machine. Now I would like to give another developer access to this machine.

I've used https://github.com/bhurlow/machine-share to export the machine from my account and import into her account.

```
> docker-machine ls
```

shows the machine has been imported into her account successfully.

```
> docker-machine env [machine-name]
> eval $(docker-machine env [machine-name])
```

Appears to setup the environment correctly.

However...

```
> docker-compose ps
```

Doesn't list any services running on the docker-machine, even though in my account I see them all correctly.

Specifying the "-p" option doesn't make any difference.

The other developer is using the same development instance, so network connectivity to the remote docker-machine is not an issue.

Is there something else I need to do to allow the other developer to see the deployed services?

Just in case it makes a difference, the development instance we're using is an EC2, running Amazon Linux. The docker-machine is ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. I forgot to let the other developer know which branch I was working on, so her version of the docker-compose.yml was not correct.